# Laravel routing pattern - url having multiple items

Tags: php, laravel-routing

My URL is something like this: http://localhost/sample/public/category/Electronics/Computers and Tablets/Tablets/iPad

Here is the list of Electronics, Computers and Tablets, Tablets etc are Categories and Sub categories. There may be N number of categories...

Is it possible to write a patterns that match the N number of categories instead of mentioning them individually as {cat1?}/{cat2?}/{cat3?} like it is done in the code below?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'category'], function () {
        Route::get('/','CategoryController@show');
        Route::get('/{cat1?}/{cat2?}/{cat3?}', 'CategoryController@show');        
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make Route with one parameter as regex pattern. Something like `category/{params}` where `{params}` is something like `(/.+)+`. Then in your controllers action you can get list of categories by parsing this parameter. `$categoriesArray = split('/', trim($params, '/'));`

Comment: Thanks chba for nice tip...this is working fine. Managed it with below code - Route::pattern('param', '[{a-zA-Z0-9/ }]+');
    Route::get('post/{param}', 'CategoryController@show');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/{cat1}/{cat2}/{cat3}', 'CategoryController@show')->where(['cat1' => '^(Electronics|Computers)', 'cat2' => '^(iPad)']);
```

See, if that help.